# Multi-layered Blazor WebAssembly template solution (.Net 5.0) doesn't work in Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly

I've created Blazor WebAssembly solution from the template in VS2019 (target framework is .Net 5.0) and tried to run without making any changes. It runs fine locally. But being published to Azure App Service the app can't register service worker and can't open "fetchdata" page. Those are errors I could see in browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: navigator.serviceWorker is undefined
```

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[BlazorApp1.Shared.WeatherForecast[], BlazorApp1.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[BlazorApp1.Shared.WeatherForecast[], BlazorApp1.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[WeatherForecast[]](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[WeatherForecast[]](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter converterBase)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<ReadAsync>d__20`1[[BlazorApp1.Shared.WeatherForecast[], BlazorApp1.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__3`1[[BlazorApp1.Shared.WeatherForecast[], BlazorApp1.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__9`1[[BlazorApp1.Shared.WeatherForecast[], BlazorApp1.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at BlazorApp1.Client.Pages.FetchData.OnInitializedAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

What could be wrong here? What is the difference in running Blazor locally and in Azure?

Comment: I raised the [issue in Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1296737/blazor-webassembly-template-project-throws-errors.html)

Comment: You should [raise a support on portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), not feedback.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: @Svetlana have you resolved your issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: Hi @10101, no I have not, and stopped experimenting with Blazor after that. Sorry can't help you on this

Comment: @Svetlana I have actually found a solution and got Blazor running on Azure. I can maybe post my solution as an answer for others facing same problems. If you ever get back to Blazor, fee free to come back to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

***It is recommand to recreate a sample project then deploy.***

## Update

[image]

[image]

## Suggestion

1. Upgrade your vs2019 to lastest.
2. Choose `.Net 5.0` .

[image]

3. If the problem still exists, it is recommended to replace a resource group or region for testing. If the problem no longer occurs, it is recommended to raise a support for help.

**1. Create project.**

[image]

**2. Deploy and test.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Jason, it seems the only difference was my Azure AppService was set to .Net Core runtime stack. I tried to change it to .Net 5 (Early Access) with no luck. I also tried to create a new AppService instance and recreate a solution from the same template - again with no luck.
I noticed that I used the same region as you - Central US. And one moment - could you please show how looks Fetch data tab and browser console?
Because the main page in my case is shown correctly as well - troubles begin when I try to open Fetch data tab + there are errors in the browser console.

Comment: @Svetlana I have updated my answer. You can see gif in it.

Comment: @Svetlana You should raise a support ticket on portal, not feedback. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: @Svetlana The problem you encounter is not a typical problem. I can only provide solutions. If the method in my answer cannot be solved, it is recommended to re-create a resource group and replace a region. If possible, it is recommended to replace a PC. Try, there may be problems with some settings during the publishing process.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having some paths in my controller pointing to images. For example I was pointing to "default" images should be used in user profiles. This was working on my localhost environment, but was dropping exceptions on Azure as Azure server was not able to find these images in specified paths. This was leading to JSON exceptions mentioned in original Question above.

For example I used:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
        string.Concat(this.WebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "\\images\\avatar.png"));
```

it should have been:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
   Path.Combine(this.WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "avatar.png"));
```

However this is not my main point of answer. Main point is how to find these exceptions on Azure server.

The key is to use Log Stream! Just setup your Log Stream in "App Service Logs" and then go to "Log Stream" to see any error messages appearing. It will point you towards any problems to be fixed during execution.

[image]